# Why Cant I use the 30GB free space to install Kubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, kubuntu, hard-drive, disk-formatting

I was trying to install Kubuntu 20.04 as a small partition on my HDD. All was going good until I was using the guided option to resize my HDD to make a partition to Install. When it finished creating the partition, I went back to confirm everything was set to the correct drive,thinking that I could go forward from there using the newly made 30gb partition, but it seems that I can not continue. How do I install to the free space without deleting the remainder of my drive's contents.

EDIT: here is the installer's image

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If a file-system is not *closed* (ie. all data written cleanly to the disk & not to *hibernate* or *fastboot* files, or partition table isn't clean, only a entire disk option maybe possible.  Check you don't have a *fastboot* or *hibernate* active on your NTFS (likely windows) partition etc.

Comment: In the screenshot, you've chosen `Guided - use entire disk`, this would do what it says, you have to chose `Manual` and then go forward and create new partition in the unallocated space. Please take a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/343268/590937).

Comment: Don't make a partition for installation.  Try starting the installation with unpartitioned free space.